# вывод значений из базы данных по условию

Tags: php, mysql

Не выводятся данные по условию. Без условия выводятся. Вот база данных и таблица.

```
-- создание базы в том случае, если ее нет
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS abc;

-- сделать базу текущей
USE abc;

-- создание таблицы в том случае, если ее нет
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1(
 id SERIAL,
 start VARCHAR(50) comment 'начало акции', 
 end VARCHAR(50) comment 'конец акции',
 name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL comment 'название товара или услуги',
 price DECIMAL(15, 2) NOT NULL comment 'обычная цена',
 price_action DECIMAL(15, 2) NOT NULL comment ' акционная цена',
 discount INT comment 'скидка',
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Вот весь файл PHP

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <style>
     ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
  }

  table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border-spacing: 0;
  }

        table {
   height: auto;
   width: 1000px;
   float: left;
   margin: 20px auto;
  }

  table th, td {
   width: 166.66px;
   padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-align: center;

   background-color: #dbe8f0;
   border: 1px solid #6897bb;
  }

    </style>
</head>

<?php
    /*ФОРМА 4*/
 /*===ПОИСК ДАННЫХ В БАЗЕ===*/
    if($_REQUEST['find']) {
        function funFind() {
            //ключевое слово для поиска
            $word = $_POST['serch'];

            //открытие соединения с сервером базы данных (SQL сервер, SQL логин, SQL пароль)
   $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345');

   //выбор базы данных (база SQL, переменная соединения)
   mysql_select_db('abc', $connect);

            //запрос
   $query = "SELECT start, end, name, price, price_action, discount FROM t1";
            //$query = "SELECT start, end, name, price, price_action, discount FROM t1 WHERE = 5";

            //выполнение запроса и запись выполнения в переменную
   $run = mysql_query($query, $connect);

   //результат - массив
   $result = mysql_fetch_array($run) or die(mysql_error());

            echo '<table><tr><th>начало акции</th><th>конец акции</th><th>название</th><th>обычная цена</th><th>акционная цена</th><th>скидка в %</th></tr>';
   do{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$result[0].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result[1].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result[2].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result[3].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result[4].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$result[5].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
   } while($result = mysql_fetch_array($run));
   echo '</table>';

   //закрытие соединения
   mysql_close($connect);

   //отмена повторной отправки формы
   header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   exit;  
        }
    }
?>

<body>
 <form id="f4" name="form4" action="" method="post"></form>
 <input type="text" form="f4" name="serch" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="submit" form="f4" name="find" value="Искать  данные" />
 <br />
 <br />
 <?php
  funFind();
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Данный запрос работает.

```
$query = "SELECT start, end, name, price, price_action, discount FROM t1";
```

Вот этот запрос (он за комментирован) **уже не работает!!!**

```
$query = "SELECT start, end, name, price, price_action, discount FROM t1 WHERE = 5";
```

Запрос с вводом через поле ввода так же не работает.

```
$query = "SELECT start, end, name, price, price_action, discount FROM t1 WHERE id = ".(int)$word."";
```

Что я не так делаю? Подскажите.

Comment: Во-первых во втором запросе у вас написано `WHERE = 5` а должно быть хотя бы `WHERE id = 5`

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, я исправил `WHERE id = 5`, данные не выводятся

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, самое интересное, что если я делаю такой же запрос в консоле MySQL, данные выводятся, а на странице сайта не выводятся.

Comment: @Anton меня пугает Что у id   стоит serial

Comment: ShilgenЭто специальный псевдоним, применяется к столбцам идентификатора записи, расшифровывается как: bigint unsigned not null auto_increment unique , где: bigint — тип большое целое; unsigned — беззнаковое; not null — значения null запрещены; auto_increment — автоматически увеличивается; unique — только уникальные значения;

Comment: а как вам удается отправить заголовки через header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) уже после того, как вывелась часть html. еще funFind вы вызываете без условия, а функцию определяете в условии. и если не $_REQUEST['find'], то она не определена. зачем это?

Answer (score 1):

А что передаётся в пост-данных, ключевое слово для поиска по столбцам базы данных "start, end, name, price, price_action, discount" или всё же ID объекта? Используйте оператор LIKE в запросе для поиска по нужным столбцам.

В вашем случае запрос может выглядеть подобным образом:

```
$query = "SELECT start, end, name, price, price_action, discount FROM t1 WHERE start LIKE '%$word%' OR end LIKE '%$word%' OR price LIKE '%$word%' OR price_action LIKE '%$word%' OR discount LIKE '%$word%'");
```